# Ember Cli Upgrades

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Instructions provided here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases lead me to believe that in order to upgrade Ember and/or Ember Data to a newer version, Ember-cli must also be upgraded.  Is this true?  The Ember-cli website doesn't mention versioning much, which always leaves me guessing whether or not to upgrade.  Is there a one-to-one relationship between a version of Ember-cli and a version of Ember/Ember Data?  Can someone please clarify?

Comment: What Mirza said in his answer is basically the gist of it. Additionally here's a [script](https://github.com/nem035/ember-install) I wrote that will manually uninstall your current ember-cli and install a version you specify (or the latest by default) :)

Answer (score 1):

Version of ember-cli are not connected with version of ember. When you create a new project with ember-cli 2.6.2 it will create a new app with ember 2.6 specified. You can still use it and specify different version of ember in your app...even 1.x.

You should always upgrade ember-cli version to the latest. You do not have to upgrade to latest ember. Ember Team has this part very well done so you can be assured that your app will run in new versions with deprecations warnings.

You could use the latest ember-cli but still use ember 2.1 for example. It is important which ember version you use which is specified inside bower.json

```
{
"name": "awesomeapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.2.0",
    "ember-data": "2.2.1",
```

in my example I am using ember-cli 2.6.2 but still version of ember is set to 2.2.0.

So you can always use latest ember-cli whenever it is released but skip the part in release that says this

```
Project Update
rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp -- Delete temporary development folders...
```

You can check the releases here for ember-cli and notice that it always states how to upgrade the tool and how to upgrade the project if needed.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused.  I have a working project that uses ember-cli 2.4.1, Ember 2.4.1 & Ember-Data 2.4.0.  I want to upgrade Ember-cli to 2.6.2, but leave Ember & Ember-Data at their current versions.  Are you saying that I just need to do the 4 steps specified in "Setup," and ignore the 5 steps specified in "Project Update?"

Comment: Yes you can just upgrade ember-cli. Version of ember is specified in bower.json. In one of my projects I am using latest ember-cli which is 2.6 with ember set to 1.13. These two are not connected (only for new project creation)

Comment: That seems inconsistent with the upgrade instructions.  If you don't delete the content of the node_modules folder in the project & reinstall.  The old ember-cli stuff would still be in that folder & used by the project.

Comment: You may want to check package.json. This is where reference to ember-cli is used as dev dependency. But if you have already latest version installed you can just do bower install or bower update to update project dependencies.